# How to apply same class with different effect in global css and specific component in angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I have used leader-line js in my angular project when this js run on my component it generates SVG line on this component view it's ok but the problem is when I move to another component it always shows that SVG. I figured out when it renders it generates a class leader-line on svg. I set on global css .leader-line{display:none;}
so it hides successfully from global but not showing on component view.
That's why I want to change .leader-line{display:table} in component style
I hope that will be work. But I can't figure out how to solve this.

Comment: if you share a MVCE, it'll make it easier to help

Answer (score 0):

Angular [encapsulates](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) component views so that they are contained within their own sandbox *shadow dom*, and won't be affected by global styles. You will need to change this setting in your component

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.none
})
class MyComponent {
}
```

*Note on view encapsulation:*

> None means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.

With encapsulation set to done you should be free to override the rest of the global css within your component